# emulate pressing key combination and send it to running program

Tags: linux, bash, key, emulation

maybe I haven't searched hard enough, but I do not seem to find the answer for my situation.

I have program invoked via command1

```
$command1
CONSOLE(provide key combination):
^Ecd
[line down]
^Eco
[up]
^Ec.
exit
```

With above program, I need to press ctrl+e cd, ctrl+e co and ctrl+e c. key combinations to perform what I need and then exit.

I need to automate above task so it's done by some script in the background:

```
white true do:
command1 | somecommandthatsends ctrl+e cd ctrl+e ctrl+e c.
sleep 9999999
done
```

Can that be achieved somehow?

Comment: Sounds like a job for [tag:expect]